# Windowless FireBreath Plugin on Mac OSX using CoreAnimation

Tags: macos, safari, core-animation, npapi, firebreath

I am using FireBreath 1.7 building a plugin for Safari 6 (and up) running on Mac OS X 10.8.5 (and up). The purpose of the plugin is to display video.

I have so far implemented support for CoreGraphics and CoreAnimation drawing models following the FireBreath example BasicMediaPlayer.

Performance is significantly better with CoreAnimation (which I implemented in OpenGL), and therefore my preferred choice.

The problem is that when using CoreAnimation, the plugin does not appear to honor the z-index, it just paints over everything. This is an issue because I would like to style my plugin video element (e.g. rounded borders).

I am aware of [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebreath-dev/pyYiH--Ehm8) from 2012 (by one of the main authors of FireBreath), which basically confirms this being a limitation of CoreAnimation.

However, according to [this article](https://www.escapedthoughts.com/weblog/geek/P110308-mac-npapi-plugins/) this should no longer be a limitation for NPAPI plugins in Safari 5 and up:

> One caveat is that Safari 4, and Chrome up to at least Chrome 10, do not composite Core Animation plugins correctly. For those of you coming from a Windows or Linux NPAPI background, it's akin to windowed-mode plugins, drawing above all web content regardless of z-index. If that's deal-breaker, you'll need to use CoreGraphics and do a readback from an off-screen OpenGL buffer. Hopefully this will be fixed within a couple more releases of Chrome (it already works in Safari 5).

Which leads to my question: Does anyone know whether it is possible to achieve proper windowless behavior in FireBreath based plugins using CoreAnimation in newer Safari browsers on Mac?

Comment: The only way I know of to determine the answer to this question is to try it.  Sounds like your results with that method aren't encouraging :-/

Comment: Thank you Taxilian for taking a look at my question. Yes, I have indeed tested this and when using CA I get the "paints over everything" issue (CG works fine, but performance is bad). Is this something for which changes need to be made to FireBreath? I am asking because it appears this should no longer be a limitation of Safari/CA.

Comment: It's possible, but if so I don't know what changes would be needed.